# Magento2 Search Query

Tags: magento2, search

I have faced the problem in using `Magento2` with search result commonly search based on `SKU` but I want to search product using the name of the product  so I want to change the search query in `Magento2` but I am not found any option in admin section and code file so can anybody help me to change search query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, i suggest you to override the core catalog_search and search module first and then you can get solution inside the model folder.

Check this 2 files:
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Layer/Search/Plugin/CollectionFilter.php  afterFilter(){}

vendor/magento/module-search/Model/Query.php  getSuggestCollection(){}

Hope this can be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I will try this solution and get back to you with my comments. Thanks for your valuable information.

Comment: Feel free to ask anything if you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set AND operator in your elastic search json queries, Override the module-elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/Query/Builder/Match.php. file in your custom module and then The code you have to edit in the build function in line no 75

```
if($matchKey != 'match_phrase_prefix'){$matchQuery['operator'] = "AND";}
```

Also make sure you are not setting the operator in match_phrase_prefix.

After this you'll get exact matches in catalog search.

This has been tested well for magento CC 2.4.0

Comment: This is not working with M2.4.1 & M2.4.2